# How to use 'helm test' without Tiller and Helm 2

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I'm using Helm 2 without Tiller in readiness for Helm 3 by using the following commands:

```
helm template --name HelmReleaseName --output-dir ./Output ./HelmChartName
kubectl apply --recursive --filename ./Output
```

I'm interested in using `helm test` to run tests against my Helm release to make sure it's running. Is it possible to do this without Tiller in Helm 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not possible. 
Precisely, Tiller maintains all releases and stores all needed information in  Kubernetes ConfigMap objects that are located in Tiller namespace

When you create yaml files and apply them using `kubectl apply --recursive --filename ./Output` - you create objects in your cluster, but not appropriate ConfigMaps and release itself .